# PDO обрезает ответ

Tags: php, pdo

Я использую PDO для получения данных из БД. В БД есть таблица tbl_pages где в поле content (тип LONGTEXT) хранится большой, на 300 000 слов текст. Я получаю запросом данные из этой таблицы, но PDO обрезает ответ до 100 000 слов. Никак не могу понять причину...
Я написал уже простой код на чистом php - но все равно PDO режет ответ

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'test-db';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'passroot';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT content FROM tbl_pages WHERE id=19');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo $row['content'] . "\n";
}
```

На всякий случай прикладываю запрос создания таблицы из которой для теста тяну данные

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_pages` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `parent_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `level` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `left_key` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `right_key` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `url` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `header` VARCHAR(350) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `image_extention` VARCHAR(350) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `access_lvl` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `main_template` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT 'main',
    `module_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `content` LONGTEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `url` (`url`),
    INDEX `left_key` (`left_key`),
    INDEX `right_key` (`right_key`),
    INDEX `level` (`level`),
    INDEX `type_module` (`module_id`),
    INDEX `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Подскажите, почему PDO режет ответ в поле, где много данных?

Comment: `bindColumn` c `PDO::PARAM_LOB` вам в помощь, наверное.

Comment: или это еще мб https://stackoverflow.com/q/24781930/1216425

Answer (score 1):

teran, спасибо!
Да, дело оказалось в параметре MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE. По-умолчанию в PDO этот параметр равен 1Mb - он и режет ответ